# Django: Point not passing from ModelForm clean to Model clean

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, geodjango

I have an `Occurrence` model that I am putting as `TabularInline` on the admin page of another model. It has a `PointField` and a `PolygonField`, of which at least one must exist.

Here is part of the model:

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    bounding_polygon = models.PolygonField(null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        # Checks if at least one of the spatial fields is filled in
        if not self.location and not self.bounding_polygon:
            raise ValidationError('At least one of the spatial fields (point or polygon) is required.')
```

In the `TabularInline` I wanted to put the `name` and `location` but when I add new rows the map of the `location` does not appear. To get around this problem, I used a form where you can enter the latitude and longitude, which is then converted to the `Point` of `location`.

Here is my form:

```
class OccurrenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    latitude = forms.FloatField(
        min_value=-90,
        max_value=90,
        required=False,
        help_text="Enter coordinates as an alternative to selecting a point on the map."
    )
    longitude = forms.FloatField(
        min_value=-180,
        max_value=180,
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta(object):
        model = Occurrence
        exclude = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OccurrenceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        coordinates = self.initial.get("location", None)
        if isinstance(coordinates, Point):
            self.initial["longitude"], self.initial["latitude"] = coordinates.tuple

    def clean(self):
        data = super(OccurrenceForm, self).clean()
        #if "latitude" in self.changed_data or "longitude" in self.changed_data:
        lat, lng = data.pop("latitude", None), data.pop("longitude", None)
        if lat and lng:
            data["location"] = Point(lng, lat, srid=4326)
        return data
```

Here is my TabularInline model:

```
class OccurrencesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Occurrence
    fields = ('name', 'latitude', 'longitude')
    show_change_link = True
    extra = 1
    form = OccurrenceForm
```

However, the `Point` created for the `location` in the `ModelForm` is not passed to the `Model` `clean`.
I have tested this same `ModelForm` without being in a `TabularInline` and it works without problems.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post the solution, since it might be useful for someone.

---

The problem was that I did not put the `PointField` that I have defined in the model into the `fields` defined in `OccurrencesInline`.

The solution was to add the field, but as I didn't want it visible I hid it using `forms.HiddenInput`.

```
class OccurrencesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Occurrence
    fields = ('name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'location')
    show_change_link = True
    extra = 1
    formset = AtLeastOneFormSet
    form = OccurrenceForm
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.PointField: {'widget': forms.HiddenInput()},
    }
```